# Questions in discrete mathematics

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

So , I am working on some past papers and these are the questions I am not sure about:
**Choose the correct answer

$ f \equiv [\neg P(x,x) \land \neg \exists x \exists y (P(x,y) \land P(y,x)) \land \forall x \forall y \forall z(P(x,y) \land P(y,z) \rightarrow P(x,z))] \rightarrow \exists x \forall y P(x,y)$**

- f is logically valid
- f is true for every interpretation in a finite world
- f is true for every interpretation in a infinite world
- none of the above

> I am trying firstly to make sense of what it tries to say: ''if P is not a reflexive relation , and they are not two elements related in both directions and if P is transitive then there is an x for every y such that x is related to y . How can I judge if this is true? If my world was integers ans $P(x,y) \equiv x<y$ the sentense holds true but that's not strong enough to answer the question

### ***The set of all subsets of natural numbers has the same cardinality with the set of real numbers***

This statement can not be proved

```
6. - This statemnt is true

7. - this statement is false

8. - this statement is equivalent to the "continuum hypothesis" by Cantor
```

> I went for 8 . The $P(N)$ is uncountable , so is the the set of real numbers and  because I think the continuum hypothesis, states that there is no cardinality between the one of natural numbers and the one of real ones , then it must be $|P(N)| = |R|$ . But I think , that the statement is also true and can not be proved?

***We define as A sets that satisfiy this property: "There is a set $B \subset A$, such that $|A| = |B|$. The number of subsets A of
natural numbers that satisfiy this property is countable***

- True
- False

> To be honest, I am not even sure that I get this question. So for example A could be the set of even - positive  numbers (subset of natural ), or odd , or primes or even something more abstract like {1,6,8,...,2n+4,...}. So basically A could be a random subset of naturals so the numbers of A set is equal to the P(N)? (or I did not get the statement). If so, the statement is false ,P(N) is uncountable.

***The powerset of prime numbers has the same cardinality with rational numbers .

- True or False***

> False. Rationals are countable. But the powerset of prime numbers can be proved by diagonalisation that it's not.

Comment: The premise of the implication in the first problem is that $P$ is a strict partial order.  So in English, the sentence translates to, "Every partial order has a greatest element."

Answer (score 1):

For the first question consider the empty relation on any set $A$, finite or infinite: it is certainly irrelflexive and asymmetric, and it is vacuously transitive, so $f$ is not necessarily true either in a finite world or in an infinite world. This also shows that it is not logically valid.

Note that your own example, taking $P$ to be $<$, shows that $f$ can be either true or false in an infinite world: it’s true on $\Bbb N$, but it’s false on $\Bbb Z$. And if you take the relation to be $\{\langle 0,1\rangle\}$ on the set $\{0,1,2\}$, you get a non-empty counterexample to $f$ on a finite set.

The statement in the second question is true and can be proved; it is **not** equivalent to the continuum hypothesis.

A subset $A$ of $\Bbb N$ has the property in the third question if and only if some proper subset of $A$ has the same cardinality as $A$. This is the case for every infinite subset of $\Bbb N$. If $A\subseteq\Bbb N$ is infinite, let $a=\min A$, the smallest integer in $A$; then $A\setminus\{a\}$ is a proper subset of $A$ that is also countably infinite, so $|A\setminus\{a\}|=|A|$. $\Bbb N$ has uncountably many infinite subsets, so it has uncountably many subsets with the property in question. It is not true, however, that **every** subset of $\Bbb N$ has the property: the finite subsets do not. If you remove even just one element from a finite set, you get a set with a strictly smaller cardinality.

Your answer to the last question is correct.